# How to find if string contains sub string with format (spaceNUMBER-NUMBERspace)

Tags: php

I would like to check if string contains any form of the following pattern

(*space*NUMBER-NUMBER*space*) ex ( 1-0 )

something like:

```
$str1 = '21-02-2017 - child 1-9 my parent';
$str2 = '21-02-2017 - child - my parent';

$bool_val= True;

if(checkContain($str1))
{
    $bool_val = True; //True because contains ( 1-9 )
}

if(checkContain($str2))
{
    $bool_val = False;
}

function checkContain($str){
    // ??
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: You may wanna check the documentation found in the [official PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php). And of course all the [PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.pcre.php) that can use the PCRE specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do a simple regex:

```
function checkContain($str){
   return preg_match("/ [0-9]-[0-9] /",$str);
}
```

Add a `+` next to the `[0-9]` to match any number of digits

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using Regular expression e.g:

```
\s\d+|\d+\s
```

And you have to use method in php for matching this pattern which will return **true** if there is any match otherwise **false**